# MKMapView fade in but won't fade out via animation

Tags: ios, animation, mkmapview, fade

I've been trying to fade in an MKMapView when we have successfully found the address, and fade out the view when long & lat == 0. I have the code in the delegate:

```c
- (void)didCompleteMapsRequestWithLatitude:(double)latitude andLongitude:(double)longitude
```

Simple actions work as expected (e.g., setHidden:YES or setHidden:NO) at the correct time.

My problem is that while the fade in seems to work well every time it's called, the fade out animation doesn't appear to happen. It's as if the only call is setHidden:YES.

My fade code is as follows:

```c
 //no location found
 if (location.latitude == 0 && location.longitude == 0)
    {
        //fade out
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        [self.map setAlpha:0.0];

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [self.map setHidden:YES];

    }
    //we found the location on the map
    else
    {
        [self.map setHidden:NO];

        //fade in
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        [self.map setAlpha:1.0];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Note I get the same behaviour using animation blocks with iOS 4.0.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to run [self.map setHidden:YES] when the animation completed, like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
            animations:^{ 
                self.map.alpha=0.0;
            } 
            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                self.map.hidden=YES;
            }];
```

Comment: Success! It worked... why does calling the .hidden there matter?

Comment: self.map.hidden=YES; is identical to [self.map setHidden:YES]; The difference is, you are turning hidden to YES right away after the animation is set, which doesn't give enough time for the animation to complete.